# C++, win32 api: How to create an html rendering window so that your application would get callbacks from JS calls?

Tags: javascript, c++, windows, winapi, html-rendering

What I need is simple: we have a console app project. We want to have such a function that would open a simple window with nothing but html (default system based) html + js rendering window that would read some default html+js string (form string or const char*). we want to have our own api joined with default js api so that when JS calls some `our.function(argument);` we would have our C++ application performe some function and for example cout argument. How to create such thing on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. CoCreate the MSHTML com object for HTML Documents:

   CComPtr spDoc;
   HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_HTMLDocument, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void**)&spDoc);
2. Do something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/parse_html.aspx) to read your HTML string and make the document render it.
3. Depending on what you need in terms of callbacks, you can use the [COM DOM Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741322%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to traverse the tree, and then sink the appropriate [DispInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741864%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get events on the elements you're interested in.  I would recommend this.
4. If what I suggest in #3 isn't good enough for you (and I'd like to hear why) then you can implement your own ActiveX control and have script on your page call methods on it as suggested by raj.

Comment: And I suspect there is a way of doing it using Gecko if you'd rather do that.  It may be easier if you're not familiar with COM.

Comment: Does this also require instantiating a web browser control (like `CLSID_WebBrowser`), or is all rendering done using `CLSID_HTMLDocument`?

Answer (score 1):

Brushing aside any security / cross browser/platforms concerns you can use implement an ActiveX object in your C++ that you can invoked from javascript.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The host for the `WebBrowser` control can provide an object that will be accessible to scripts via the `external` object.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041.aspx#GetExternal