# C++, Qt, QtWebKit: How to create an html rendering window so that your application would get callbacks from JS calls?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, webkit, cross-platform

What I need is simple: we have a console app project. We want to have such a function that would open a simple window with nothing but html QtWebKit html+js rendering window that would read some default html+js string (form string or const char*). we want to have our own api joined with default js api so that when JS calls some `our.function(argument);` we would have our C++ application performe some function and for example cout argument. How to create such thing using Qt?

PS: this question is [related to my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479116/c-win32-api-how-to-create-an-html-rendering-window-so-that-your-application-w) , I just suddenly got Idea that doing it once for all platforms would be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [QWebFrame::addToJavaScriptWindowObject()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject). It lets you expose a C++ QObject to the javascript in your page. Your html+js can then call C++ methods on that object from the web page.