# Does rendering HTML to a window require CLSID_WebBrowser, or just CLSID_HTMLDocument?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com, activex

I apologize, but I'm a little confused.  I was wondering what the simplest way to render an HTML string to an `HWND` is.  This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479116/c-win32-api-how-to-create-an-html-rendering-window-so-that-your-application) suggests that all you need is `CLSID_HTMLDocument`.  But does that suffice for rendering?  I would have thought that to render, you'd also need `CLSID_WebBrowser`.  Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done either way, it is a matter of how much of OLE/ActiveX your client implements.

Personally I prefer using CLSID_HTMLDocument and then requesting the window as needed but I was implementing the OLE support rather than relying on an existing framework so your mileage may vary. I suspect with an existing very complete framework the CLSID_WebBrowser route may well be easier.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how to obtain the window from CLSID_HTMLDocument?

Comment: Get the ParentWindow property (by calling get_ParentWindow when using c++)